# How to read these Dynamic Data fields using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have situation where the Data from the XML is as below. I want this data in the format shown after below Input XML

```
**Input XML:-**

<JLINKMetadata>
    <photos>
        <EventNumber>
            <string>120423007237</string>
            <string>120602009897</string>
            <string>071030-3242</string>
            <string>071022-2374</string>
            <string>071010-2484</string>
            <string>071018-2894</string>
        </EventNumber>
            <EventDate>
                <dateTime>2012-04-23T06:27:00</dateTime>
                <dateTime>2012-06-02T18:53:00</dateTime>
                <dateTime>2007-10-30T20:35:00</dateTime>
                <dateTime>2007-10-22T16:45:00</dateTime>
                <dateTime>2007-10-10T16:50:00</dateTime>
                <dateTime>2007-10-18T19:40:00</dateTime>
            </EventDate>
        <DOB>
            <dateTime>1965-07-08T00:00:00</dateTime>
            <dateTime>1965-07-08T00:00:00</dateTime>
            <dateTime>1965-07-08T00:00:00</dateTime>
            <dateTime>1965-07-08T00:00:00</dateTime>
            <dateTime>1965-07-08T00:00:00</dateTime>
            <dateTime>1965-07-08T00:00:00</dateTime>
        </DOB>
    </photos>
</JLINKMetadata>
```

**Following is the Existing XSLT Format in which I want the above XML data....**

```
<PersonPhoto>                 
    <!--PersonPhotos.EventNumber-->
    <EventIdentification>
        <IdentificationID>EVT12345</IdentificationID>
    </EventIdentification>

    <EventDate>
        <!--PersonPhotos.EventDate-->
        <Date>2007-02-20</:Date>
    </EventDate>                    

    <PersonBirthDate>
        <!--PersonPhotos.BirthDate-->
        <Date>1981-02-20</Date>
    </PersonBirthDate>

</PersonPhoto>
```

**Here is the Output XML how I wanted finally:-**

```
<Photos>
    <PersonPhoto>
        <EventIdentification>
            <IdentificationID>120423007237</IdentificationID>
        </EventIdentification>
        <EventDate>
            <Date>04/23/2012</Date>
        </EventDate>
        <PersonBirthDate>
            <Date>7/8/1965</Date>
        </PersonBirthDate>
    </PersonPhoto>

    <PersonPhoto>
        <EventIdentification>
            <IdentificationID>120602009897</IdentificationID>
        </EventIdentification>
        <EventDate>
            <Date>10/22/2007</Date>
        </EventDate>
        <PersonBirthDate>
            <Date>11/6/1945</Date>
        </PersonBirthDate>
    </PersonPhoto>

    <PersonPhoto>
        <EventIdentification>
            <IdentificationID>120602009897</IdentificationID>
        </EventIdentification>
        <EventDate>
            <Date>5/12/2011</Date>
        </EventDate>
        <PersonBirthDate>
            <Date>1/3/1955</Date>
        </PersonBirthDate>
    </PersonPhoto>

</Photos>
```

Thanks in Advance.. Hope someone could help me with this situation...

**Here is what I tried so far.. and yielded only 1 record of PersonPhoto shown in expected output xml above .. My aim is to capture every record whose occurrence is dynamic**

```
<xsl:variable name="Photos" select="photos"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$Photos"> 
  <PersonPhoto>                 
    <!--PersonPhotos.EventNumber-->
        <EventIdentification>
      <IdentificationID>
    <xsl:value-of select="EventNumber/string" />
      </IdentificationID>
        </EventIdentification>

    <EventDate>
        <!--PersonPhotos.EventDate-->
        <Date>
        <xsl:value-of select="EventDate/dateTime" />
        </Date>
    </EventDate>                    

    <PersonBirthDate>
        <!--PersonPhotos.BirthDate-->
        <Date>
        <xsl:value-of select="DOB/dateTime" />
        </Date>
    </PersonBirthDate>

</PersonPhoto>
```

Comment: Help, yes, but not do in its entirety. Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Hi Utkanos I updated my post to display what I tried so far..

Comment: When you say "Following is the Existing XSLT Format in which I want the above XML data", do you mean that is the existing XML output of the XSLT that you've written?

Comment: Are you restricted to XSLT 1.0, or can you use 2.0? If the latter, there are some additional options available, such as `<xsl:for-each select="1 to count(photos/EventNumber/string)">`.

Comment: Thanks Larsh... You approach works too.. But, in this situation I have to loop through each element with the position of the parent element.. Otherwise I end up getting all the elements in one record unlike it is shown in Output xml above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of it, your for-each operates on the photos element, of which there is only one. If I understand correctly, you want it to instead iterate over the (6 in this example, could be ## next time) entries in the children of EventNumber, EventDate, and DOB. Try iterating over photos/EventNumber/string. Each iteration, grab the position in a variable ($pos), then replace the value-of occurrences with `<xsl:value-of select="." />`, `<xsl:value-of select="../../EventDate/dateTime[position() = $pos]" />`, and , `<xsl:value-of select="../../DOB/dateTime[position() = $pos]" />` respectively. If you have multiple

Comment: Looks like the start of a good answer, but did you mean to finish the last sentence?

Comment: I had meant to have it say use nested for-each loops if there are, in fact, multiple photos elements. Somehow it got truncated.

Comment: Yup... I have been using For-each loops anyway. When you said each Iteration I felt the same. Thanks again

Comment: AlwaysWrong ---> I have another request for you. Could you please take a look at this Question ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954788/reading-count-of-dynamic-xml-boolean-values-through-xslt